# How to change text between <li> tags with jQuery in WordPress?

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

I am using WPML plugin to translate a website and I have a plugin that does not seem have the kind of strings that can be translated.

What I want to do is change the text 'Nici un rezultat...' between the 'li' tags in the following code using jQuery. Or do you suggest other method?

```
<div id="aws-search-result-1" class="aws-search-result" style="width: 225px; top: 339.828px; left: 1026.03px; display: block;">
   <ul><li class="aws_result_item aws_no_result">Nici un rezultat...</li>
   </ul>
</div>
```

Here is my full code https://codepen.io/SilviuIsidor/pen/gGdxMg and here is the actual webpage: https://isidors.com/test/dupex/en/store/

How can I do it?

Comment: $('.aws_result_item').innerHTML = 'some new text';

Comment: I tried $('.aws_result_item.aws_no_result:lang(en)').innerHTML = 'some new text'; and ('.aws_result_item:lang(en)').innerHTML = 'some new text'; and it does not seem to work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use *jQuery* function [`.text()`](http://api.jquery.com/text/)

```js
$("ul li").text("Your new Text");
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="aws-search-result-1" class="aws-search-result" style="width: 225px; top: 339.828px; left: 1026.03px; display: block;">
   <ul><li class="aws_result_item aws_no_result">Nici un rezultat...</li>
   </ul>
</div>
```

This will change the text of all the `li` tags for an advanced selection(ex: first `li` tag, last `li` tag, nth child ...) use the [jQuery Selectors](https://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/)

Comment: @SanchitPatiyal Yes, my answer is based on the posted code

Comment: I can't just use $("ul li").text("Your new Text"); This is my CSS selector "#aws-search-result-1 > ul > li" anything I try it doesn't seem to work. What's wrong?

Comment: @SilviuIsidor please share the full code, cause my answer worked with the portion of code that you posted, then I think the problem is not here !

Comment: @Mehdi Bouzidi it's a WordPress page https://isidors.com/test/dupex/en/store/  <li class="aws_result_item aws_no_result">Nici un rezultat...</li> is the "results no found" text in the search bar. I have tried it myself in external code editors and it works, but in wordpress it fails. You can see the full html with inspect element.

Comment: Here's my header text <script type="text/javascript" src="https://isidors.com/test/dupex/wp-includes/js/admin-bar.min.js?ver=4.8.2">
<script>
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
  $('.aws-search-form:lang(en)').find("input[type=text]").each(function(ev)
  {
      if(!$(this).val()) {
     $(this).attr("placeholder", "Search...");
  }
  });
});
     
$('.aws_result_item').innerHTML = 'some new text'; 
</script>

Comment: @SilviuIsidor edit your question, by posting **HTML** and **JS** full code please, don't put code on a comment

Comment: @MehdiBouzidi I did.

Comment: @SilviuIsidor I'm lost in your code we must lunch a chat

Comment: @SilviuIsidor I can't found the `div` with `id=aws-search-result-1`

Comment: @Mehdi Bouzidi that's because it only appears when you type something into the search bar and no results could be found check it with the inspector tool on the actual webpage www.isidors.com/test/dupex/en/store

Comment: @SilviuIsidor Check if you've add the **jQuery CDN** after that add this script `$('.aws-search-form').find("input[type=text]").on("keydown",function()
 {
   document.getElementById("aws-search-result-1").find("li .aws_result_item").text("NEW TEXT");

 });`